# Need help concatenating .JS

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I have the following statement.

```
var myStr = "This is the first sentence. ";
myStr += "This is the second sentence. ";
```

My end goal is to make the statement appear like this:

This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence.

But when i run code in **console.log** I get this instead.

```
"This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence."
```

How do i remove the qoutes without affecting the qoutes used as strings

Comment: Build myStr over several lines by concatenating these two strings:
"This is the first sentence. " and "This is the second sentence." using the += operator.

Comment: myStr should have a value of This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence.
Use the += operator to build myStr      (These were assigment isntructions).

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are added by `console.log` to characterise the logged value as a string.

There's nothing wrong with your concatenation, everything is working as expected. In case you need control over your exact output, use [`process.stdout.write`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) insted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStr = "This is the first sentence. " + "This is the second sentence.";
```

Only need whitespace after(.) and it will work.